# How to make friendly url in liferay

Tags: java, liferay, friendly-url

I have my portlet placed in a page and the portlet is rendering with the values from the url parameters. but I need to hide the values and show friendly url..

check this url...

> http://betatest.businessworld.in/web/guest/storypage?CategoryID=37489&articleId=215754&version=1.1&journalArticleId=218207

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check this url , http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/optional%3A-adding-friendly-url-mapping-to-the-portlet , Hope that will solve your problem

Comment: Thnx.. Perfectly Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have access to liferay but in manage pages section in admin area their is a input field which takes name of friendly url. Can you please check

Comment: YEs but if you see my url, it is actually friendly by using the method you are saying. but I need to hide the extra parameters showing in the url.